# lstat returning <0

Tags: c, file, stream, macros, directory

Basically, this should be a simple piece of code that opens a directory stream and looks for symbolic links. Whenever a symbolic link is found, it should print ("Symbolic link found");
However, the `lstat(dirp->d_name,&buf`call always returns a value < 0, and I don't know why.
I created the two symbolic link opening the file folder, opening a terminal window inside the folder and running
`ln -s ciao.txt link1` and 
`ln -s ciao2.txt link2`
I know I should call  `closedir()` later in my code, please don't care about this.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char buffer[100],dir[100];
    struct stat buf;
    int x;
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;
    if((dp=opendir(argv[1]))==NULL)
    {
        printf("\nError opening directory stream, now exiting...\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    while((dirp=readdir(dp))!=NULL)
        {
            lstat(dirp->d_name,&buf);
            if(S_ISLNK(buf.st_mode))    
                printf("\n%s Is a symbolic link\n",dirp->d_name);
            else
                printf("\n%s Is not a symbolic link\n",dirp->d_name);



        }


}
```

Some help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I checked the lstat call, it is returning <0 and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d_name` is the file name in the directory, not a full path name. You must eather `chdir` into the directory you are looking at, or construct full path names for the files.

The simplest solution is to add this line just before your `while` loop:

```
chdir(argv[1]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Basically, If I wanted to do that "my way" I would need a full path name like /home/myuser/Desktop/myfile etc.  right?

Comment: Yes, if you don't want to use `chdir` you need to construct the full path name of the file. (Or, just to be complete, you could also use a relative path name, such as `../../../Desktop/myfile`.)

Comment: Just one last thing since you seem very confident with files in C. Do you know how can I avoid getting those `..` and  `.` files showing in my code? I don't even know what they refer to. Thanks.

Comment: `.` is a link to the current directory, and `..` to the parent directory in the directory tree. Just check for those file names, for example using `strcmp`, and skip them.